# Laravel's Serialization on "Jobs" Table's Migration

Tags: php, laravel

While looking at the migration of the "Jobs" table, a question came to my mind. As you know, Laravel uses *SerializesModels* trait to serialize models and their relations when the job is processing. AFAIK, this trait uses PHP's own serialize() function. Here is where the question begins: Laravel uses *LONGTEXT* data type for migration.

```
$table->longText("payload");
```

but PHP recommends *BLOB* data type for [serialize()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) function's output.

> Note that this is a binary string which may include null bytes, and needs to be stored and handled as such. For example, serialize() output should generally be stored in a BLOB field in a database, rather than a CHAR or TEXT field.

Why is Laravel using *LONGTEXT* instead of *BLOB*?